# PartialLinkText doesn't work in typescript

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, selenium-webdriver

I have list of elements as below:

```
<div class="container-menu" _ngcontent-c13="">
<nav _ngcontent-c13="">
<ul _ngcontent-c13="">
<li _ngcontent-c13="">
<a class="" _ngcontent-c13="" href="/32info" role="link" routerlinkactive="active" ng-reflect-router-link="/32info" ng-reflect-router-link-active="active" title="Information"> Information test </a>
</li>
<li _ngcontent-c13="">
<a class="active" _ngcontent-c13="" href="/32address" role="link" routerlinkactive="active" ng-reflect-router-link="/32address" ng-reflect-router-link-active="active" title="Address"> Data address </a>
</li>
```

I wanted to first click on element two and then first in my test. I appealed this way:

```
element(by.partialLinkText('Data address')).click();
element(by.partialLinkText('Information test')).click();
```

but this doesn't work now. How can my tester click on these items?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the full compiler experience for TypeScript with Selenium WebDriverJS, add the type definitions to your project, for example using NPM.

```
npm install --save-dev @types/selenium-webdriver
```

The source code for the type definition is on [GitHub](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/selenium-webdriver),